# Wherever you are... Happy Thanksgiving

Tags: discussion

We live in tumultuous and troublesome times; some of us have suffered  personal losses while  others are counting their  successes...

Whatever side  of the cosmic fortune cookie  we crumble into, we should find time to put aside our differences, sit together (at least in spirit), tilt a jar and thank Providence for our continuing survival...if only for 24 hours in any time zone.

Most cultures have a harvest festival, a celebration of life and its promise for the future.

... from our culture in the Americas...

Happy Thanksgiving to All,

...but we have to do better for our children.

There might be far fewer Thanksgivings in the future.

Comment: Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about English Language and Usage in any sense. (It also assumes that all members on this list are citizens of the US, in case the poster did not know.)

Comment: …nor is it a question. Unless the poster is conducting a poll on list members' happiness.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is offensive.

Comment: @Chenmunka How is this offensive? If you are going to give a woke argument, you should know that my paternal grand-parents are Native American...For us Turkey Day meant a full belly and happy heart. Hunger does not understand woke politics.

Comment: @Cascabel If you want to query the closure of this question, please write another. Don't edit this one.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I am less than happy with this treatment...it was supposed to be an example. How can I cite a closed post?/and I object to the deletions of my comments..I have screen shots which I will show on demand to Meta

Comment: @AndrewLeach I would hope that you could offer more advice other than "write another one"

Comment: @Cascabel Of course you can cite a closed post. People do it all the time. Deleted comments had descended into bickering and nastiness. Which rather undermines your "Can't we just be nice" post, I'm afraid. If you would like advice, I'd advise to use Meta for its purpose of asking about the site.

Comment: If that is what you got out of my comment, then you did not get my intent: 
@AndrewLeach I did not descend into nastiness...I have screen shots. If this is gonna become a 'cross-the pond' issue then I do not wanna participate here anymore, but I think I was treated badly by some users who have a Euro-centric  political axe to grind.... mostly  anti-American

Comment: BTW @AndrewLeach that other post was based off your radical and unapproved edit of my edit  of this post when it was asked for an edit to make it more on-topic. Wow...Did I get that right?

Comment: note to self: disappeared files from mod...see edits

Comment: Odd this post is closed. We’ve had a number of thee over the years and they always bring some warmth. But I don’t want to spoil my holiday mood by actually reading the comments describing why it was closed. In any case, happy holidays and thanks for the warm post. {{{ <— camp: you may rest here, weary traveler.}}}

Comment: @DanBron I am coming back after a few months....thank you for your supporting comments. I felt so unwelcome based on the comments that I left off participating until I arrived here again quite by accident while tracing another thread...